# Epicor Prophet 21 Pricing Engine

Tags: epicor

We are using Epicor P21 as our primary ERP/Accounting System. It has its own pricing engine. Now, we are going to implement a third party Pricing software called PriceFX.
Does anyone have any experience in customizing Epicor P21 to alter its pricing engine, to make it use a third party pricing engine instead of it own engine.
We'd like to hear your technical experience of this integration.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you post this question on [epiusers](https://www.epiusers.help/). It's an amazing resource with a large community of ERP users.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Pricefx has the ability to export & import data in numerous formats ...all the way from simple SFTP based CSV files to a more sophisticated ReST API call. Provided the Epicor system can import ( or export ) in some manner, Pricefx can most likely provide a link. Generally speaking, in Pricefx terms, your needs would fall under the Pricefx Integration Engine technology ...I teach a class in this for Pricefx and have yet to find an integration which we cannot accomplish.